# sources input failing validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this logic that is in a form that some users are able to process without selecting a source. Is there a better way to do this logic so it will not fail I am unable to get it to fail so I am very limited.

html

```
<div id="sources">
      <label id="lblSources" class="control-label">* Source</label>
      <label id="lblSourcesError" class="pl-4 text-danger" style="display:none">At least one 'Source' must be selected</label>

       <input type="checkbox" value=@item.Value name="chkProduct" />
</div>
```

Js

```
var checked_sourcecheckboxes = $("#sources input[type=checkbox]:checked");
if (checked_sourcecheckboxes.length == 0) {
    $("#lblSourcesError").show();
         additionalValidation = true
    }
    else {
    $("#lblSourcesError").hide();
}
```

Comment: Some users may have javascript disabled so perform server-side validation on top of the client-side

Comment: This code would appear to be executed once when the page loads. It is not associated with any event. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  var checked_sourcecheckboxes = $("#sources input[type=checkbox]");
  if (checked_sourcecheckboxes.filter(":checked").length == 0) {
    $("#lblSourcesError").show();
    additionalValidation = true
  } else {
    $("#lblSourcesError").hide();
  }
  checked_sourcecheckboxes.change(function() {
    if (checked_sourcecheckboxes.filter(":checked").length == 0) {
      $("#lblSourcesError").show();
      additionalValidation = true
    } else {
      $("#lblSourcesError").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sources">
  <label id="lblSources" class="control-label">* Source</label>
  <label id="lblSourcesError" class="pl-4 text-danger" style="display:none">At least one 'Source' must be selected</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value=@item.Value name="chkProduct" />
</div>
```

This checks the status when the page loads and whenever the checkbox is changed.